# Kendo Search Box Using .query Clears Styling

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo grid with custom styling and a search box.  The styling is created by the `.DataBound` event.

```
.Columns()
.Filterable()
.Pageable()
.Events(events => events.DataBound("onDataBound"))
.Toolbar(toolBar => toolBar.Template(@<text><input class='k-textbox' value="Search..."
         onfocus="if (this.value=='Search...') this.value='';"onblur="this.value = 
         this.value==''?'Search...':this.value;" id='searchbox'/></text>))  

function onDataBound(e)  
{
//ton of styling  
}

function addSearch() {
    return { searchbox: $('#searchbox').val() };
    }  
$('#searchbox').keyup(function () {
    var q = $("#searchbox").val();
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.dataSource.query({
        filter: {
            logic: "or",
            filters: [
              { field: "User", operator: "contains", value: q },
              { field: "City", operator: "contains", value: q },
              { field: "Business", operator: "contains", value: q }
            ]
        }
    });

});
```

The problem is that this new search function immediately rids of all the styling found in `onGridDataBound` and uses it's own.  I've tried simply calling `onGridDataBound` within the search function but nothing happens.

There must be a straightforward solution to this.  What am I doing wrong?

**Update**
I'm wondering if somehow triggering the dataBound event again would re-establish the styling I want however, I'm having difficulty doing this properly. I've been tinkering for awhile but it seems I can't quite grasp the documentation [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-dataBound).  I'll continue working with this route until I know this does / doesn't work or until someone answers.

Comment: @John  Please avoid making pointless edits! Removing "Thank you" from the end of a post does not improve the question!

Comment: How much space "Thanks in Advance" will take? But when 50% of questions are considered then its huge. And even if you dont thank, you will get answer.

Comment: Saying thanks at the end of a post just makes it a little more humanizing and is just generally polite.  
Looking at your revisions in your activity reveals that this is a chronic problem for you. Basically all of your 350+ revisions are simply removing the "Thanks" from the end of posts!  
 From the [help/editing](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) page: **Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it**.  You seem to be using revisions for selfish reputation gain rather than actually assisting the community.

Comment: Nope.. I am NOT after reputation. Neither my company nor myself, are after SO's reputation. I had faced such kinda problem while managing a huge XML database. After removing such unnecessary (? depends how you see) words, the size of the DB was reduced by 20% !! Thats the only reason. I learned a lot from SO. Hence my little contribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of my problem was in using the .query method for a search function in the first place.  The .query method seemingly instantiates a new grid which was why the styling was being removed.
The correct way to write a search while keeping the styling intact is to utilize the .filter method.

```
$('#searchbox').keyup(function () {
    var q = $("#searchbox").val();
    var int = parseInt(q);  //required for fields that are of type int
    var grid = $("#gridWorkflows").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.dataSource.filter({
        logic: "or",
        filters: [
            {field: "Id", operator:"eq", value: int},  
            {field: "User", operator:"contains", value: q},
            {field: "City", operator:"contains", value: q},
            {field: "Business", operator:"contains", value: q},
        ]
    })
});
```